# Custom Bootstrap

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap-3, customization

I am very new to Bootstrap. I made a custom bootstrap using their site, and I've gotten a config.json file and a file with no extension called pax_global_header. What are these and what am I supposed to do with them?

Thanks!

Comment: `pax_global_header` sounds related to [the Unix archive format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_(Unix)); presumably your unzip utility is slightly weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config.json file that is downloaded is nothing but a reminder of what your settings were when you downloaded. I would assume there will be some future functionality that would allow you to upload that file in to the website and reproduce the customized settings, but that feature doesn't currently exist, as far as I can tell.

If you are using bower, I would suggest using it to download Bootstrap for you. You can then use a LESS file to pull in the CSS features you want, and compile it using gulp/grunt in to your public asset directory. You can also use gulp/grunt to copy over the individual JS files you want in to a single file in that same asset directory.

Comment: "there will be some future functionality that would allow you to upload that file in to the website and reproduce the customized settings" Indeed, it's coming in v3.2.1: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13790